# Mysql Group Yii Active Record by Date/Time

Tags: php, mysql, yii

This code returns the lists of scheduled posts(name, datetime).

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='name, datetime';
$criteria->condition='datetime>:datetime';
$criteria->params=array(':datetime'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$criteria->order='DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%d/%m/%Y") ASC';
$models = Posts::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

I would like to GROUP posts with same date d/m/Y and then only represent the H/i/s for each, its possible?

Like:

```
Array
(
    [2000/10/10] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] = Post 1
                    [time] = 12:10
                )
        [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] = Post 2
                    [time] = 16:20
                )
        [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] = Post 3
                    [time] = 20:30
                )
    )

    [2000/10/11] => Array
    (
        [6] => Array
                (
                    [name] = Post 6
                    [time] = 10:00
                )
    )
)
```

Comment: You want GROUP posts through mysql query or on result array returned by findAll ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for getting time you should select

```
 $criteria->select='name, DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%h:%i") as time';
$criteria->group='date(datetime)';
```

for getting the o/p as desired use php logic

Comment: select DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%d/%m/%Y") as sortorder and at last group by sortorder, i dont know yii syntax

Comment: But my doubt is the code to group them. Only $criteria->group='DATE_FORMAT (datetime, "%d/%m/%Y') '; should work this way?

Comment: can u just echo raw sql query.?

Comment: Thank you Arun Killu, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how exactly your results look, but of course you can do that.
Try something like this:

```
$array[$models["date"]][]["name"] = $models["name"];
$array[$models["date"]][]["time"] = $models["time"];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple extension that handles this, its called [XDateView](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/xdateview) (disclaimer: I'm the author), its specific to display records grouped by date. if you need something more advanced/configurable you can use another excellent extension called [GroupGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/groupgridview) that has a lot more features, and allows you for more customization and control.